# How can I add a flex component programmatically from within a Papervision Class without using this.parent...?

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, actionscript, flex4, papervision3d

I have a flex application and a papervision BasicView. I would like to add a new flex UIComponent (such as a button) from within the papervision class. I have posted the full example code below. It works but I would like to be able to accomplish my goal without the "(this.parent.parent as Group).addElement(button);" line.

```
<!--Application MXML-->
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:Application xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
        xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
        xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx" minWidth="50" minHeight="50"
        creationComplete="Init()" applicationComplete="Start()">
    <fx:Script>
        <![CDATA[
            import mx.core.UIComponent;
            import spark.components.Button;
            public var start:QuickStart;
            public function Init():void
            {
                start = new QuickStart();
                var uicomp:UIComponent = new UIComponent();
                addElement( uicomp );
                uicomp.addChild( start );
            }

            public function Start():void
            {
                start.GoTime();
            }
        ]]>
    </fx:Script>
</s:Application>


//QuickStart.as
package{
    import org.papervision3d.view.BasicView;
    public class QuickStart extends BasicView
    {
        public function QuickStart()
        {
            super(500, 500, true, true);
        }

        public function GoTime():void
        {
            var button:Button = new Button;

            //this is the offending line
            (this.parent.parent as Group).addElement(button);
        }
    }
}
```

The version I have does work so please excuse any minor typos.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Logically you would dispatch an event inside your `BasicView`, listen for it in your main application, and create the button from up there. In a prefect OOP world, every class should be a black box sending events :)

Comment: +1  "In a prefect OOP world, every class should be a black box sending events"

Comment: I agree completely. +1 as well for that last sentence. But if I do it that way, how would I maintain access to that button? What if I create the button in my BasicView, dispatch an event with that button as the target, have the main application add the button when it hears the event?

Comment: Why do you need to keep access to that button in your `BasicView`? Target should not be tweaked like you want to do; if you need to send something along with an event you should create your own type of Event including a property.

Comment: That's actually what I meant and got my terminology mixed up. I've been working with Flex/AS3/Papervision for a month or so. I'm in the process of implementing the custom event right now.

Comment: Anyway I still think you should create the Button in your main application... putting a component in an event is reeaally strange (but ok, you're free to do it :p). When you have to create a custom event its mainly to put some data in it (an index, a string, an object), not a visual component. Why again do you need to have a reference to the button in the BasicView?

Comment: The component would be created in the BasicView and passed up through the event to be added by the main application. In this case simply think of the button as object and not as a visual component if that helps. I need access to the component from within the basic view so that I can programmatically create and modify it at runtime. The component is going to be used as the material for a papervision plane and created with content collected in realtime. This probably isn't the proper way to fulfill my need but it's the way that I have to do it right now. I'm just trying to clean it up a little.

Comment: I accepted your answer rather than answering the question myself since you gave me the idea of how to proceed. The method described in my last comment worked wonderfully. The only issue was that I created an Event Dispatcher class so that I wouldn't have to add event listeners to each level of hierarchy. Thanks for your help! I now have a few more ideas of where different areas could be improved.